# Educational manga about a mad scientist

Tags: identification-request, manga

I tried to ask this on Science Fiction but it was off-topic.

I remember, in kindergarten to first grade (late 2000s or early 2010s), reading a kids' manga comic book from the public library.

I think it featured some sort of mad scientist who somehow taught scientific things. He looked like Einstein with spiky white hair and wore a lab coat. I am sure there was some sort of other main, less weird character who was smaller in stature (maybe a kid).

I think it took place in the scientist's laboratory.

It might have not been educational, but I think it was. It was lighthearted and I believe the plot was secondary to the educational parts or jokes.

I am quite certain it was a translated manga; it read right to left and had one of those notes that says you're reading the wrong way behind the back cover. I don't remember much else.

I think the cover featured the aforementioned mad scientist and his sidekick.

I am quite certain it was targeted towards kids (**not** relatively dark but technically for kids like *Naruto*.)

I think the volumes were about the size of single Viz volumes (i.e. of Shōnen Jump series). It was in black and white. I don't think it was *Dr. Slump* based on what I know of the series from appearances of the characters in *Dragon Ball*.

It definitely read right-to-left, and had one of those things explaining it (just like in Viz books).

The library was in the United States, so the series was very likely released there. It was translated to English.

Comment: Possibly one of the "The manga guide to ____" / "manga de wakaru". They're from around 2010, officially licensed, and at least some are targeted towards kids (I'm guessing the calculus one is still for high schoolers). [Molecular Biology](https://nostarch.com/mg_mbiology.htm) includes a professor-like character, but he's bald, not spiky haired, and not on the cover. I believe they're all available to borrow on archive.org.